# Why is line-height set in px affected by parent’s font-size?

Tags: css, font-size, line-height

I've made this example: http://codepen.io/tomsoderlund/pen/JYJpPR to demonstrate.

I’m setting the `font-size` (=size of 1 em) on the parent (`.canvas`) using:

```
$('.canvas').css('font-size', emSize + 'px');
```

Both the `font-size` and `line-height` are set in px. `font-size` is (correctly) *not* affected by the parent’s em size, but the `line-height` is - why is that?

[image: EM layout animation]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

line-height only applies to block level elements. You have to add display:block to your span.

> On block level elements, the line-height property specifies the minimum height of line boxes within the element.
>
> On non-replaced inline elements, line-height specifies the height that is used to calculate line box height. On replaced inline elements such as buttons or other input elements, line-height has no effect.

[MDN line-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height)